# JAVA (Serialization without transient keyword)

Tags: java, serialization

Say I have 100 variables in a class which implements the `serializable` interface.

I do not want to serialize 70 of those variables. How can I do this without using the `transient` keyword?

Comment: You can use embedded class.

Comment: If you have 100 variables in a class you have a design problem, not a serialization problem.

Comment: @Kayaman, completely agree. We can always use a DB to store similar or processed data

Comment: why can't you use the transient keyword?

Answer (score 0):

Define a [serialPersistentFields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serial-arch.html) member that defines the members to be serialised.